# Parsing HH:MM in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a bash script:
I have a parameter set to 02:00 eg. PARAM=02:00.

I have a date in the format YYYYYMMDDHHMMSS, eg SAMPLE_DATE=20160101000000.

How can I add this PARAM to this SAMPLE_DATE?

eg: SAMPLE_DATE+PARAM = (20160101000000+02:00) = 20160101020000.

I have split PARAM got the minutes and then using date api I added these minutes to the date, but Could there be any other better option for this one?

Comment: Please let us know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: I am using cut, as one of the option to derive minutes out of this PARAM 02:00 and forming a date(20160101020000) out of it by adding these minutes to date(20160101000000). But I didn't like this approach, I am looking for some other option to add this 02:00 to date(20160101000000). Thanks!

Comment: Er, no, you should update your question. Comments offer *terrible* formatting, and your question should be self contained.  Try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us your work so far.

Comment: Also, bash has no "date api". Your operating system comes with a `date` command which external to the shell, but its options and usage vary from OS to OS.

Answer (score 1):

Your input format is not recognised as is by GNU `date` so you will need to modify it, by truncating the date to use the YYYMMDD part only, and then adding the HH:MM part. Then you can use the output formatting options to get what you want:

```
$ D=20160101000000
$ PARAM=02:00
$ date -d "${D:0:8} $PARAM" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
20160101020000
```

Comment: His input format could very well be recognized by `date`. Check out [the `-f` option](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date) for advanced input format handling. (And note that this question was tagged [tag:unix], not [tag:linux].)

Comment: Thanks guys! This ain't help, let me try more!

Comment: @ghoti `-f` is a BSD extension that is not supported by POSIX or GNU `date`.

Comment: @chepner - yes, and the `-d` option is a Linux extension that is not supported by POSIX or BSD `date`. That's the point. This question is about `bash`, not about a particular unix variant's options for the `date` command. If it was, the OP would have communicated what operating system they are using.